# Why was I always told "This post does not meet our quality standards."?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to post a question just now, but I was always told "This post does not meet our quality standards" when I clicked the "Post Your Question" button. Why? The screenshot of my question is here:

[image: Low quality post]

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the title, which is important in the quality filter. What was it?

Comment: @JoachimSauer "what is the endianness of int in Java?"

Comment: Yes, but how did u know that? I haven't posted it yet.

Comment: See the title bar of the browser !!!!

Comment: :-). So, could you please answer that endianness question first?

Comment: Oops, I've missed that ;-)

Comment: @user2384994: actually the endianness of variables is not defined in Java, as there is no way you can ever observe it. Only when you convert them into bytes will you be able to see an endianness and then it depends on how the conversion is done. Also, I'm pretty sure that's a duplicate of another question on SO.

Comment: I'm not sure what the site rule on the matter is, but I would tend to shorten titles by turning a question into a statement, then have the question as first line of content.  E.G. the title might be "Endianness of int in Java".  Often I'd remove 'in Java' as well, but here it seems directly relevant to the inquiry.

Comment: By "when you convert them into bytes" do you mean "when you convert them into bytecodes"? So, the author made a mistake, right? The excerption of the book is here: http://i44.tinypic.com/5xkaye.png

Comment: @user2384994: no, i meant "into bytes". "into bytecodes" is not meaningful here. Bytecode is the native binary format in which executable Java code is represented and is not at all relevant to this discussion. (Oh, and yes: I'd say the author is wrong, because endianness of variables in Java is pretty much undefined).

Comment: I see. Thank you, Joachim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) here explains it all. **Excerpts are :**

Make sure your question has

1. a clear title
2. a reasonable explanation of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
3. correct use of English and actual sentences
4. proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation

*If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit on our network.*

Comment: Thank you. So the reason is that my question is so brief? But the error message appears immediately after I clicked the post button, so the briefness of the question should be judged by computer, not by human. So, how long can make the server think my question is not brief?

Comment: @user2384994: The computer algorithms are kept secret so that human beings can't come up with posts that are "just under the wire." Basically, you need a decent title and a "reasonable" amount of text to past the filter.