# Respected user makes post "not meet quality standards"

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

Today I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685014/image-causes-pixelated-image). It did [*not meet Stack Overflow's standards*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) until I added backticks in the title. A more respected user removed the backticks in the title an hour ago.

I think it is counterproductive if respected users and the authors of the quality standards do not agree on what *quality* means.

Comment: we can not format content of title as `code formatting` and i can see there is no need to write backticks so imho its perfectly fine to edit

Comment: Adding ticks might have helped you circumvent the filter. It did not make your title better. So perhaps the filter should be adjusted to ignore the backticks.

Comment: You could have tried other things first, e.g. "<image> tag causes pixelated image" or "Pixelated image when using <image>".

Comment: Also please don't "brute force answer" or whatever that is. Wait until you can post an answer before posting an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I won't wait. Someone might be wasting his time trying to find the same solution.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I think "brute force answer" means "this is what I already tried, which is a brute force solution", not "I'm editing my posts to use brute force to circumvent a SO time limit".

Answer (score 16):

The quality filter is not super smart. For example I have seen posts in which someone adds the "it does not meet our quality standards" sentence (sometimes more than once) and then the post passes the filter. Clearly, that is not actually a better post.

When these "false passes" occur, high rep users sometimes edit the post to make them genuinely higher quality. This does not mean they are deliberately trying to make your post fail to meet quality standards.

Your best future action would be to improve the quality of your posts in ways that satisfy both the automated filter and the humans who clean up after it.

- Use capital letters at the start of sentences and for I
- Include code in your post (not your title) and format it as code
- Ensure your title is a meaningful sentence and don't start it with a lower case letter
- Include enough information in your question to enable others to answer it

By and large your question was ok, except for the tag in the title. This is a case where people are smarter than the filter.