# Why does my question not meet your quality standards?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow, but when I post the question I get this error in a red box:

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make
>   sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you
>   have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

My question body:

> When i merging 2 drives in win7, at the middle of merging my computer
>   turned off (power unplugged).
>   Now i have the made drive. and i can see all folders and files of two
>   drives when i using Explorer but i can't opening any file of this
>   drive!
>   can you help me to recover files contents? can i repair filesystem or
>   reformat drive without lost files?

Why does this not meet your quality standards, and what can I do to address this?

Comment: Besides the language problems, that particular question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. So you should not ask it there.

Comment: In English, sentences start with a capital letter, and the personal pronoun **I** is capitalized as well.

Comment: Have a look at [the changes we made to this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/184702/revisions) to see what we mean.

Comment: Thanks! I think that problem is solved!

Comment: You should have paid attention to the first comment, [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143681/lost-files-content-after-break-merge-drives-in-win7) is going to be closed as it is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Spelling and grammar both matter. The string "i" is not a word in the English language.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your question matter appears more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) rather than [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).  Please have a quick read of each sites topic list (located [here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for Super User and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow) so that in future you can post to the right site and avoid having your question closed as off-topic.

As for the quality issues, you should take a look at [this Meta FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).  This hints that in order to avoid being stopped as low quality, a question must have:

> - a clear title
> - a reasonable explanation of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual sentences
> - proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation

You definitely need to make some changes to point four, as mentioned in comments "I" needs to be capitalised in English.  It *might* also help to put the first part of your question fully in the past tense - "I merged/opened" rather than "I merging/opening".

You didn't post your question title here but make sure that it succinctly but accurately describes your problem, and perhaps make more of an effort to tell the community what you have tried already.

Comment: Just as a note: Data Recovery questions on Super User normally end with two answers: 1. You can accept to lose data? Use testdisk; 2. You need the data badly? Give it to a data recovery company.