# Why Stack Overflow gives me "this question body does not meet our quality standard"

Tags: support, quality-filter

I'm trying to ask the following question, but I'm told it does not meet your quality standards:

> Hey i am willing to build a spectacles for blind people.  So i am
>   willing to using a Microcontroller to process image to determine where
>   obstacles are smooth or rough.  If smooth a sound generator gives a
>   sound to this blind people to understand there is a obstacle.is this
>   possible?
>
> How can i process image? matlab or opencv?  is matlab code or openCv
>   code loaded into any MCU?  if possible then what kind of MCU can i
>   use?   (i am a beginner.so please help)

How can I improve my question so I can ask it on your site?

Comment: How is your title related to your question?

Comment: i want to post this.But stack over flow give me "this question body does not meet our quality standard"

Comment: Well, it doesn't here either.

Comment: is anybody please tell me how i post this and meet quality standard?

Comment: Stack Overflow-specific questions belong on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), not here on Meta Stack Exchange. And about the question you want to post, it's both too broad and primarily opinion-based, so it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: is there anything wrong with my writing format?

Comment: I don't know how Stack Overflow checks for the question quality, but the question is off-topic. See my previous comment why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Comment: May be you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9):

Using standard English will help.

- The first-person pronoun "I" is *always* capitalized in English.
- Punctuation does not have a space before it but does have a space after it.
- Sentences generally start with a capital letter.

Of course, at first glance your proposed question is too broad. "Is this possible" is not really the kind of question that should be asked on Stack Overflow. (Not to mention, this question *itself* should have been asked at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).) So even if you clean it up so that it passes the quality filter, I expect that it will be closed in short order.

Comment: I see you've managed to post [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27509387).

Comment: Reads the part needed to post the question, ignores the part where the question is problematic.  A for effort, F for understanding.  Upvote for you, though!