# Make a duration bar and a button that shows how much you have corrected

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I want this so that on **Feed** I can see how much I have to wait and, if for example it shows me that I have been banned then on duration bar will show if I’m banned temporary or permanent. On temporary it shows the count down and make the count down to start when all the posts are 100% corrected.

And make for each user to have on each posts percentage button which shows: dark which means bad, yellow which means good and green which means green, 100% correct post.

And when a user writes an answer or a question, then it will show a bar with colors that have a line and the line will move according to how much you have corrected. Because, I really need to know wether I’m banned permanently or not.

What do you think about that?

Comment: There is no way for a machine to identify how good or bad your post is. That’s why we have humans as an integral part of the system. So the red/yellow/green indicator you already have: the score of your post, the aggregate of votes cast by humans based on their assessment of its quality. As for a timer: question and answer bans are typically indefinite, and are only going to be lifted if you edit your old posts and they then get upvotes, or if you use your once-in-6-months freebie post well and it gets enough upvotes. In other words, the timer you want would always say: *T minus eternity*.

Comment: @DanBron But what if there’s nothing edit in correct way?

Comment: @DanBron Now what to do with this post? Can you please help me to edit this post in a proper manner where the down votes I have can decrease until I start to increase the up votes? Please?

Comment: Don’t worry about this post. It’s on Meta. Its score and downvotes don’t matter in any way. They don’t effect your reputation and they don’t effect any bans. All they mean is people think “I don’t like this idea”, that’s all. You can put this post out of your mind.

Comment: @DanBron Buț How can I make my ban message be lifted?

Comment: There’s nothing I or anyone can tell you beyond what’s in the duplicate of this post. Honestly, it’s true. Even mods can’t manually lift bans. The only possible advice is in the dupe target.

Comment: @DanBron Ok, I understand this, but that really effects my account on **Meta SE**, there’s another way of showing some agreement or disagreement, is by writing the answer below.

Comment: **Because** [voting is different on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), it is very very hard to get question-banned here. So again you don’t need to worry about this post. Let it go. (And no, as that link shows, the appropriate way to agree or disagree with a proposal on Meta, unless you have something material to add, is to vote. That makes it easier to see which proposals are popular or unpopular and prioritize accordingly. It’s what voting is for). All that said, there’s nothing I can do for you and nothing else I can tell you. My best advice is: let it go.

Comment: @DanBron Ok, I understand…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's literally no way to write an algorithm that will tell you if your post will be well received.  Judgement is too much of a subjective metric to be able to automate that functionality.

What we already do is look for signs of bad posts, such as uncapitalized sentence starts, lack of spacing and punctuation, and other basic grammar failures.  Those are usually good indicators that the post lacks effort, and will therefore receive downvotes.  Depending on how bad it is, it may even hit, ["does not meet our quality standards"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards), and be prevented from posting until it's resolved.  That's about the best you're going to get.

As for being banned, please read [What can I do when getting, "We're no longer accepting questions/answers from this account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).