# The new Code of Conduct references are so obsolete they harm the Code of Conduct: is this repairable?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

I wonder what the point is of a Code of Conduct that refers to supporting material that's so out of date that the supporting material now violates the Code of Conduct? I certainly support the idea of being nice to each other, but what's the point of continuing to refer to guides, blogs, etc. that were written so long ago they're contributing to the problem rather than helping solve it?

I decided to ask this question after following the pop-up on my page this evening announcing the latest version of the Code of Conduct. I started reading and re-discovered there are minimum standards for asking questions! I was overjoyed! Over at Worldbuilding where I spend most of my time, the idea of minimum standards is regularly questioned and those of us who try to police those standards are considered draconian. So I believed I'd found a useful resource to direct people to beyond our aging and outdated Stack-specific help pages.

I wasn't just disappointed — I was surprised.

The new Code of Conduct refers to a Meta question [that was written twelve years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/395595). Before realizing how old it was, I thought I'd found a useful resource for helping people deal with the CommunityBOT automated "your question doesn't meet the minimum standard" message (I'm paraphrasing, of course). Then I noticed the answer to that question (the "policy") has a comment indicating one of the links ([Eric Raymond's *How to ask questions the smart way*](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html)) was terribly out of date. Yes... yes it is. Written between 2001 and 2014 (as far back as *twenty-two years ago!*) the page includes the following observation about people who get upset when criticized:

> Get over it. It's normal. In fact, it's healthy and appropriate.
>
> Community standards do not maintain themselves: They're maintained by people actively applying them, visibly, in public. Don't whine that all criticism should have been conveyed via private e-mail: That's not how it works. Nor is it useful to insist you've been personally insulted when someone comments that one of your claims was wrong, or that his views differ. Those are loser attitudes.
>
> There have been hacker forums where, out of some misguided sense of hyper-courtesy, participants are banned from posting any fault-finding with another's posts, and told “Don't say anything if you're unwilling to help the user.” The resulting departure of clueful participants to elsewhere causes them to descend into meaningless babble and become useless as technical forums.

In essence, the proffered advice *isn't wrong.* But doesn't *how it's said* reflect the attitudes that eventually led to the Code of Conduct changes that led to Monica Cellio being fired? (Forgive me, but I laughed outright when I read that third paragraph due to the irony of users using the Code of Conduct in ways that trend in that direction and yet linking to this to explain itself. But I digress....)

I spot-checked a number of other links found via the current Code of Conduct and while some of them are reasonably current, far too many of them simply aren't. In fact, I can even see from those decades-old resources why Stack Overflow was cursed with the toxic environment I hope it no longer suffers. Frankly, the Code of Conduct would be (granted, IMO) *better* if all the supporting links were deleted. It's not helped by the reality that too much of the Help Center is also obsolete (c.f. [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)).

To conclude, my question has morphed a bit (and I apologize for that). Could Stack Exchange stop making changes to the Code of Conduct until it brings all the supporting material that's supposed to be justifying the Code's policies up to date? Or at least curate those links and remove those that no longer reflect the Code's intentions?

*And please don't suggest that the community-at-large do that. My own experience with getting "official" pages updated is that the community-at-large can't do it.*

Comment: what's stopping you from writing the answer post you want to see?

Comment: It's repairable by either removing the references or updating them. But nobody knows if it will be repaired.

Comment: The passage you are quoting shows a mockery attitude that is also pretty evident in the "You were downvoted because Tim lost his key" old meme. It is not the first time Stack showed an attitude that blames the victim for not being tough enough... not being adult enough... not being "alpha male" enough. What is really funny is not that the CoC uses a 20 years old example, imho that mentality is still here. The funny part is that this is the same CoC that on surface promotes the "Be Nice" principle.

Comment: Can you explain why you find that quote from Raymond's post problematic? I don't see it. The use of _his_ instead of _their_? The _loser attitudes_? The CoC doesn't say anything about not criticizing. Constructive criticism is still welcome.

Comment: @terdon the extreme generalism that seems to assume that by default if an user is angry because of a comment or downvote that is because *they* are at fault, the comment / downvote was appropiate criticism and they are "not tough enough" or even "losers". By itself this quote could pass by as simply poorly written, but **imho** it takes a different flavor when you remember the "Tim lost his key" meme that actually makes fun of users trying to understand why they were criticized without apparent reason, implying that they should grown up and learn to disregard such things instead of being kid

Comment: @starball Frustrated experience. I've spent years discussing and proposing policy changes on various Stacks (mostly [worldbuilding.se]). But if the mods aren't interested in updating the Help Center, there's no path to success and all that effort disappears under the weight of other Meta posts. I'd be happy to participate in such an effort (after so many years, I think updated community wikis for many of those support links would be valuable), but not one word before Stack Exchange signs a blood oath that they'll adopt it.

Comment: @terdon Please take a moment to read though Eric Raymond's entire post. Vast swaths of it are pretty good (other than being entirely Stack Overflow centric due to SO being, well... pretty much the only Stack back then). It's the delivery of the message that's the problem. Sarcastic, rude, sometimes even nasty. There are worse examples than what I used, but I wanted that third paragraph because it was so terribly on-point with my overall concern of obsolescence. If we interpret the CoC's intention as inviting people to *actually* be nice rather than simply *acting* nice, ... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... then it's time to update the support material to reflect that. I don't blame Eric or any of the other contributors to those early rules. It reminds me of college and the days when Unix/Linux was written by college students who left error messages or code comments of that ilk. In my 20s it was funny. In my 50s it's immature and counter productive. IMO it's too easy to conclude SE is hypocritical when it's spent the last few years trying very hard to graduate into fully professional. There's a time and a place... and it's time (IMO) to either update the support material or cut it loose.

Comment: I don't doubt that you're right. I'm just saying it isn't obvious from the quote, and highlighting what you consider problematic would help to get your point across.

Comment: @terdon Actually, If I tried to help a poster, who responded with complaints that boiled down to "I don't want to edit my post," and I responded with, "don't act like a loser, get over it," I'd *instantly* have my comment flagged as a violation of the CoC. I don't doubt that better examples might improve my case, but all anyone need do to prove it is to start clicking on those links and seeing for themselves how damaging they are. Pity so many won't do that, but it's likely why after 20 years we're having this conversation.

Comment: "In essence, the proffered advice isn't wrong. But doesn't how it's said reflect the attitudes that eventually led to the Code of Conduct changes that led to Monica Cellio being fired?" As abrasive as ESR can be at times, he's just straight up *correct* about this one. Any "code of conduct" that doesn't admit this kind of "get over it" advice is fundamentally misguided, because *the community is actively harmed when people get upset simply because they were accurately criticized*. The Code was wrong in 2019 and it is still wrong now, although probably better on average.

Comment: @SPArcheon characterising the asker of a closed question as a "victim" is part of the problem. That's entirely what that blog post is trying to convey.

Comment: @jbh I am not attacking you here. Of course using "don't be a loser" would be unacceptable. As I said before, I am sure you are right, I am simply suggesting that if you explain more clearly and point out the issues, you will get your point across better.

Comment: @OrangeDog there is plenty of user acting toxic when they are correctly criticized or even *helped* with guidance in how to use the site. At the same time there is plenty of established user that act toxic when pretending to "help moderating the site" and harass lower rep user like they were trash for a) elitism, b) less user = less rep competition, c) pleasure in making other feel bad (when you don't know ho to be happy, at least make the others feel worse than you I guess).

Comment: Alas, terms like "help vampire" or the worse "help whore" weren't made by the "new" users, nor they made memes like "Tim lost his key". Those were made by established users and in some case even by STAFF MEMBERS. This generalization that "we are the only smart ones, everyone is stupid but we are so good that we will tell them how to grow up" is a very condescending mentality that has for long been the cause part of SO is deservedly seen as toxic.

Comment: And the staff has multiple time shown this mentality even recently: posting announcement without feedback, calling Meta "that vocal minority that gives nightmares", namecalling an user on a PUBLIC NEWS SITE ecc. Therefore, forgive me but I don't like seeing someone calling out users behaviors as "being losers" **in an official CoC**. It may slip in when talking on a chat or replying on a post, but I expect the CoC to have an higher standard

Answer (score 4):

> And please don't suggest that the community-at-large do that. My own experience with getting "official" pages updated is that the community-at-large can't do it.

I'm going to suggest exactly that though. If enough users here agree with it and there's no massive objections (hence this answer, so it can be voted on properly) I suggest we just remove that link from the meta post.

I don't think we lose much by editing it out.

Comment: Are you suggesting that all the links derived from the CoC be listed here (or as their own questions) for community judgement and that if sufficient up votes are obtained for each link they will be removed from wherever that link is found in the chain? How many votes consistitutes "enough users?" I've never yet seen what you're suggesting lead to change. I'm asking the Staff to step up and curate their CoC.

Comment: @JBH this is just for that one link, http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. If there are other specific links that are better off deleted (that you didn't call out specifically in your post, just generally hinted at), yes. Make new answers. Staff curates the CoC, users curate community wiki faq posts on meta.se.

Comment: I didn't generally hint at anything and I've never seen what you're suggesting work. Can you direct me to an example or explain to me how many upvotes are required to justify the change that I can simply make it happen?