# Generalize the DMCA Takedown Help Center page

Tags: feature-request, help-center, legal

All SE sites have [a /help/dmca-takedown page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dmca-takedown). Right now, it's very specific in both the title and the content regarding DMCA takedown requests. However, it would be helpful if it was generalized to address questions about intellectual property infringement.

I propose the following changes:

1. Change the title of the page to "How do I report intellectual property infringement?" This follows the model for the [Help Center article for reporting harassment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/harassment).
2. Add a section to define "intellectual property infringement". It should address copyright as well as patent and perhaps trademark infringement concerns.
3. Make a clear distinction between intellectual property infringement and [plagiarism, with a reference to /help/referencing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).
4. Make it clear that moderators are not responsible for legal concerns related to intellectual property and that comments and moderator flags are not appropriate places to report potential issues. The IP owner must make the appropriate notifications to the company.
5. Ensure that the pointers to the Copyright Policy and the DMCA are maintained.

This would also move [this Meta FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465/572) to a more canonical location.

Comment: What I was invited to do when I [pointed out that many of the CoC reference links were so obsolete they violated the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389695/395595) was to rewrite them and submit the rewritten page to Meta for community approval. However, no assurance that anything would actually change was given. Fair warning.