# Could users still get “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

We have a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) for a system message: [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/289691)

As of October 2023, can the users get this message?

I'm asking because recently, in Web Applications, we got a question that circumvented the quality filter by adding `&nbsp;` and `⠀` and I'm wondering if the advice to comply with the "quality stardards" is according to the current **community consensus** about the quality standards to be used **as reference** across the network.

#### Title

How do I ask a question on Stack Exchange?

#### Body

```
   ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀     ‍   ‍   ⠀
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes:

> [image]