# How do the re-open & close notifications work?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294372/identify-process-using-a-file-in-c) was initially closed (because it wasn't a "real question").

However I felt it had the potential to be a good question (even though the OP wrote it poorly) and I decided to dedicate some time to improve it, and when I was satisfied with its quality I voted to reopen.

I wanted to know if the people who voted to close will be notified of my edits and my reopen vote, so that they can vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt they will be notified. In anycase, you don't have to be the 'closer' to be the 're-opener'. The question will be bumped up in the active question tab to get attention (in a way).

Comment: @o.k.w, thanks for the reply. thats right it ll be bumped up in active question.. Only the people who have rep above 3000 can re-open... But if someone knows the answer and dont have the rep limit, then he cant reopen it and answer it..

Comment: It ll be great, there should be a notification, because it lets the closers to know the edit happened in the question, and they can re-open it if thats ok... its worth consider i believe...

Answer (score 1):

Nestled high in the snowy peaks, among the moderation tools available to 10k+ users and Diamond mods, is a magical page that shows lists of recent close and reopen votes.

Any appropriately high-rep (and attentive) user can see your reopen vote there.

[alt text http://imagebin.ca/img/nFqeiEr.png](http://imagebin.ca/img/nFqeiEr.png)

Comment: It would be nice if this tab was available to 3k+ rep users.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if the people who voted to close will be notified of my edits and my reopen vote, so that they can vote to reopen.

No, notifications are never sent to people who vote.  Whether it's upvoting, downvoting, flagging, voting to close or open, voting does not provide a feedback loop to the voters.

However, there are 2,500 people that can vote to open or close, and once you edit the question it will likely be seen by enough people to open it, especially if you make a comment saying, "I edited it, and its should be ok - please vote to re-open".

If you need additional attention, a message here (meta) can be useful.