# Shouldn't it be made clear that questions should be English only?

Tags: discussion, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't the “English only” policy be mentioned in the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40271/shouldnt-the-english-only-policy-be-mentioned-in-the-faq)

I know [it has been asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40271/shouldnt-the-english-only-policy-be-mentioned-in-the-faq), but some people really [need a NO ELEPHANT sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725263/a-quoi-correspond-20).

For [Russian questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316274/how-can-i-mount-a-network-drive-in-mac-os-x-in-java), this isn't much of a concern as it looks like basically no one on Stack Overflow knows (or knew at that time) English and Russian. But this time, people actually answered in French.

Would making this policy explicit in the FAQ be much of a burden?

Comment: +1 it might be useful to add it to /questions/ask-advice.

Comment: Did you mean to link [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40271/shouldnt-the-english-only-policy-be-mentioned-in-the-faq)? You seem to basically be asking for the team's stance on that request to be rethought, but there's no truly new material such that it warrants a new question, I don't think. Rather, rally up support for the existing request if you want this to be added to the FAQ.