# Is a suggested edit that makes question titles into actual questions a good suggestion?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, title

Right now, user [shenku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148998/shenku) is suggesting a lot of edits, where the title of a question is only changed to make it a “proper question” as in adding some interrogative word and a question mark at the end.

For example:

- “Ember unit testing with asynchronous routes” → “How to do Ember unit testing with asynchronous routes?”
- “moving text up next the image” → “How can I move the text up next the image?”
- “apply styling to parent element when child is in hovered” → “How can I apply styling to parent element when child is in hovered?”

I personally don’t like these edits, as I don’t think that questions need to have actual questions as the title, and I also think that such an edit is definitely “too minor”. I have rejected a few suggestions with that reason, but other reviewers always approved them (given that there’s nothing *wrong* with them).

Are such edits okay? Should question titles really be proper English questions?

Comment: In general, yes. But what you're really asking is if these edits are ok, right? It's depressing to reject as too minor and see that others are approving, but keep it up.

Comment: Related: [Why do people insist titles actually be a question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/68/why-do-people-insist-titles-actually-be-a-question) on Meta.SoftwareRecommendations

Comment: @KateGregory Well, I don’t really mind if my rejection doesn’t come through. In the same way that I would reject it as too minor, I wouldn’t change it back once others have agreed with it. I just want to know what everyone thinks about this practice in general, because I personally don’t like it at all.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/would-the-stack-exchange-network-be-better-if-titles-contained-complete-grammat

Comment: Btw. is there *any* way to call that user’s attention to this? I assume this doesn’t work, right? @shenku maybe?

Comment: yes, you can @-reply the edit-suggester on a post they edited. It won't appear to work because you won't get autocomplete, but it will work. (And I have had editors change their ways after I've done it.)

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks, did that now :)

Comment: @poke thanks for calling attention to this discussion, I certainly agree with the following answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99190/179512, and will endevour to make sure any edits I make fix a truly poor title.

Comment: Also related (very old) discussions: [Should question titles be phrased as questions? (A straw poll)](/q/19999/997587) and [How can we get more people to make their title a question?](/q/21606/997587)

Answer (score 4):

I've just looked at his last few edit suggestions. They are a bit of a mixed bag - I found one that IMHO is good, several that are meh, and one that was definitely too minor.

In fact the text of the questions he chose to edit is generally remarkably good - there was nothing to fix in the body of the question.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4162381) is good. Without it the title just doesn't read right. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4162377) is definitely too minor - he simply added a question mark.

The rest of what I checked are ho-hum. They're not *bad* and accepting them didn't degrade the question, but they also don't need to be done. While correct grammar and phrasing is nice, there is little value added to the questions with those suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Someone has clearly watched too much Jeopardy. (I'll take "Questions about Questions for $500, Alex")

So at a quick glance of the PHP tag, I'd say maybe 3 or 4 are actual questions. The rest are more statements about what the thread is. I agree that they don't need to be question formatted because the main reason to have them is that it's the title of your thread. Sometimes it'll be a question but, more often than not, making it into a true questions just adds extra fluff and doesn't improve the thread at all.