# English as a second language problem. Can we have a fix?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fix-my-english-please tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53668/fix-my-english-please-tag)

I find a few of the answers, made by people whose first language is not English, difficult. My worry is that some of the answers appear to be poorly written or not thought through.

Would it be possible to have a flag that the writer can use to say, "this is my second language, please contact me for clarification"

Its a small point but I feel I may have voted down a good answer I just did not understand. Or is it just me?

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Philip! This idea has been suggested before, but was ultimately (unofficially) rejected. Here's the original request: [fix-my-english-please tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53668/fix-my-english-please-tag)

Comment: You are right but maybe just a tag so others can ask for clarification? I will delete this if I get any more negative feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In a programming related site people express themselves with code, so their native language is not that important. As long as the code they have shown in their answer is readable this is enough for me.

Comment: There is more to Stack Exchange than coding.

Comment: maybe I am a bit lost.

Comment: Oh, yes, fair enough, I was referring to SO.