# Should others downvote my posts for "grammatical" reasons?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, grammar

Someone decided to start downvoting my answers due to them being too "bulletin-board-like" (not good grammar and capitalization).

Is there a way to report those users?   And if so, what can i do about it?

[Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822725/php-simple-question-function-to-function-get-variable-array/5822778#5822778)

Comment: What's stopping you using good grammar and capitalisation?

Comment: @ChrisF, nothing. but i dont feel that it is always needed to answer a question, especially if it is perfectly readable to any english speaker

Comment: I assume the question in question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822725/php-simple-question-function-to-function-get-variable-array/5822778#5822778

Comment: Ah - but it's not. Us old fogies have to work out that by "2" you mean "too" or is it "to" or even "two"?

Comment: @Wes, yes it is, among others that the same user downvoted for just as inane reasons

Comment: @ChrisF, i dont ever rly use shorthand except for maybe the word `u` aside from that its capitalization mostly

Comment: @Neal - Oh "rly"?

Comment: lol who downvoted this?

Comment: If you can show clearly - with refrences - a significant downvoting trend by this user, which shows clearly he's singleing you out I suspect something can be done. This question however doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: @Wes, how do i search all contact btw me and that user?

Comment: @Neal: Usually "btw" means "By the way". I'm seeing why you are having trouble communicating with other users.

Comment: @Neal look through your history, of answers. Particularly your recient History.  Somewhere to start http://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal#tabs-answer-user. I'd warn you that one or two probably won't count as bullying.

Comment: What bothers me more is why markus totally changed your answer in his edit.. ?

Comment: @Madmartigan in my experience `btw` usually depends on context, but you might be right... i dont know (idk...)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, me tooo?

Comment: @Neal in this case I agree with you, the change has to come from you, not other people editing your posts. For the record I didn't downvote but personally prefer any post to have good and correct grammar and syntax.

Comment: i seems I have drawn more people to the attn of both this Q and the stack Q to downvote ....

Comment: @shadow Wizard, thank you, but even after i fixed the supposed 'grammar error' i am still getting downvotes, also im not sure why im getting downvotes here.

Comment: @Neal over there it's +3/-3 so you should be happy with the +9 rep you got.. over here guess you touched a nerve that's all. Reputation in Meta should not bother you too much, I learned it over time - anyhow your question is now candidate for a FAQ so you should feel honoured. :)

Comment: @shadow, well its now +3/-4 lol. how does it become FAQ?

Comment: @Neal, I noticed a *lot* of "Why the -1?" comments on your posts. If you're gonna ask, be prepared for people to answer...

Comment: @Shog9 i do that because i want to know the reason for the `-1` and not to be just left out in the cold

Comment: @Neal: again, if you're going to ask, *be prepared for folks to answer*. By which I mean, be prepared to *learn* from their answers.

Comment: @Shog9 yes. i know that. but.... (above)

Comment: @Neal the reason is exactly what you said yourself: bad sintx and grmr

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/we-need-to-help-non-english-speakers-somehow

Comment: @Shog9 i am a native english speaker, born and raised in NY lol

Comment: @Neal: ur native english spkr? then u hv no rsn to tlk lk ths

Comment: @Neal: you should strive to demonstrate this then... ;-) (I linked it as a related question simply because it *does* relate - like it or not, there are readers who struggle to understand txtspk)

Comment: @Neal, it's my experience that non-native speakers of English often have a better grasp of "proper" english than a lot of native speakers. (Sad, but true!) This makes any argument that non-native is an excuse for using contractions like "2" for "too" a rather poor one.

Comment: w0w people are still downvoting this? ^_^

Comment: Can't tell if this user is trolling or not.

Comment: @Niklas you realize this is a really old post, right?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> what can i do about it?

Find your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, learn how to use periods, commas, and semicolons, and practice using proper grammar.

Comment: yes, but is that a legit reson for a downvote?

Comment: @Neal, I don't think it is a valid reason to downvote an answer. (Unless it is so unreadable that it is unhelpful.)

Comment: @jjnguy, so what can i do about it?

Comment: @Neal, you can start using proper English. This isn't a bulletin board or chatroom, it is a technical question and answer site that would be treated with a degree of professionalism. Would you write "u need 2 hire me" on your CV? Don't put that in your answers here, either.

Comment: @Neal, nothing.  People can decide for themselves what a valid reason is.  Just make sure your answers look more professional.  As for past downvotes, fix your old answers, and leave a comment for the downvoters if they commented on your answer.

Comment: What's the rationale behind marking this answer as CW? Afraid for downvotes?

Comment: @Chich, yeah.  It was kinda' an asshole answer.  So I didn't want downvotes or upvotes that came from me being an ass.

Comment: _Badges_ on the other hand... :)

Comment: @squill, Yeah.  I didn't expect that at all.

Comment: @jjnguy ***We don't need no stinkin' badges*** ^_^

Answer (score 24):

People can downvote for whatever reason they want. Some people see this as a valid reason.

While not enough to warrant a downvote on its own perhaps, I certainly think that:

`u need 2 use function() 2 do that`

Is less clear than using proper English.

All votes are anonymous, so no - there is no way to report them, and I am actually offended that you feel the need to do so.

`what can i do about it?`

Work on the clarity of your posts, including, but not limited to, punctuation, grammar, and spelling.

Comment: yes, but when a user makes it clear that they did the downvote due to grammar, but not due to the answer being wrong or right

Comment: @Neal - the tooltip states "This answer is not useful" that *could* include "poor grammar making it hard to understand".

Comment: How bad *was* it? Can you share? I agree this is probably a bad reason to downvote, but I can't give you a proper opinion without seeing the actual post. I also don't see this as a real problem, probably more of an isolated case.

Comment: @Madmartigan : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822725/php-simple-question-function-to-function-get-variable-array/5822778#5822778

Comment: Neal, I personally agree that the user is being a bit of a grammar-nazi, but there's more going on here than you let on.

Comment: Just want to add this: Yesterday, the lack of a *comma* in an answer I received caused it to be complete nonsense. I had to read it several times until I finally realized what the poster was trying to say.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming the answer in question came from [Function to Function get variable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822725/php-simple-question-function-to-function-get-variable-array/5822778#5822778) I don't disagree with the downvote.

If the person didn't understand how the variables had been reused they are unlikely to understand global variables. The code example in question could have been better explained.

I don't think that this is a bullying case. However I wouldn't have personally downvoted it.

Honestly if you make a bit more effort with your replies, making them clearer to understand I think your problem will go away.

Comment: Good work - the OP here *conveniently* omitted the technical criticisms that along with those regarding his style.

Answer (score 8):

Spelling, like so many other technologies, is standardized, to make life easier for developers. See this [RFC standard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/).

Answer (score 5):

The best approach would be instead of downvoting to simply edit the post to make it use proper grammar/spelling/etc.

*However*, if I were to spot a user consistently using shorthand that is confusing/unhelpful, then I would start commenting to the effect of "you consistently use shorthand or confusing abbreviations in your questions, would you please take the time to write in proper English?"

If I *still* saw the same user consistently doing the same thing, I would either alert a moderator via a flag and a note or ask the community here for advice.

Comment: that is pretty much what im doing...

Comment: @Neal you consistently use shorthand in your posts/comments; would you please take the time to write in proper English?