# Can a literate user be encouraged to stop deliberate writing errors?

Tags: discussion, spelling, grammar

As a grammar and punctuation pedant, I spend some time on fixing the quality of questions (and some answers) on SO. In the vast majority of cases, I am quite sure the OP genuinely doesn't have excellent English, and so silently improving it — in my view — aids English and non-English speakers alike, whilst avoiding direct criticism of the writer.

However today I found [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer) who I suspect is making persistent writing errors deliberately for stylistic reasons — posts are all in lower case, and all punctuation marks have space prefixes, often resulting in orphaned marks. [I politely pointed this out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14570428/472495) in the comments<sup>1</sup> but the lack of reply suggests to me that they intend to persist. A quick click through some of their writing shows that it is a popular error to fix, so thankfully it isn't just my OCD!

In general, if a user — a very helpful one in this case — is deliberately creating edit work, what can be done about it?

<sup>1</sup> Sadly, a moderator deleted this conversation, in which the user took offence, refused to justify their mistakes, and chose to ignore others who added their agreement.

Comment: Realistically...you can edit it. There is no real way, besides leaving a polite comment and hoping for the best, to address the real issue.

Comment: If the user is helpful, and its writing style is understandable and useful, who cares?

Comment: Maybe he's French. Space prefixes before punctuation marks are the norm there. I've also been told it's the norm *somewhere* in written English - maybe Canada? That I don't think is that much of a problem. The all lower case is really annoying though. I wonder where it comes from - I've seen *professors* do this

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Everyone on the Internet who reads Stack Overflow, but is not a member.

Comment: @Bart: in the question I linked to, I did so. I believe in the value of improving writing, but if the OP continues being helpful at their present rate, I will have to skip editing their material.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - indeed, I found something on FL&U today about the French convention - didn't know that before! Apparently they (should) use a "thin non-breaking space" to avoid the mark orphaning to the next line.

Comment: @halfer, yes. That's the bane of our lives outside of Microsoft Word.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, it's gets too much at some point. I remember an OP rolling back all my edits (to questions with similar problems) claiming that he could bloody well decide on his own whether or not capitals and punctuation were necessary. I think that was even on Meta...

Comment: @Robert, I understand but if the user doesn't follow repeated advice and is proficient enough that edits can't catch up to him, should we really take measures if the aforementioned proficiency is useful to the community?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Though if after they are told, and full well understand the issue at hand, they still persist, one could argue that they are actively posting below-par content, creating work for others to fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should others downvote my posts for "grammatical" reasons?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/should-others-downvote-my-posts-for-grammatical-reasons)

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA In what sense is that a dupe? It's related perhaps, but I don't see enough of a dupe in it?

Comment: @Bart it seems in the same vain.... So _maybe_ just related.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - in the same _vain_? `;-)`

Comment: @halfer yes in the same vain.... What is wrong with that word?

Comment: @Bart, indeed, then again, what can we do beside editing or commenting? The next layer goes into email from moderator (that may never be read), then into suspension territory. If the user's contributions are useful, that's counter-productive.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - heh, I thought you were misspelling deliberately on a spelling question for irony purposes. You're after the word "vein".

Comment: @halfer ahh ha... stupid multiple spelling of different words.... I never will never understand it... and I am a native english speaker.

Comment: Your you that ewe took from me is trying too pry open a can of tuna and the bad of chips two. @halfer

Comment: Unrelated, but... the user is also adding tags to their question titles, pretty consistently. =)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi [Organized manhunt](http://timsevenhuysen.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0035.jpg)? But yeah, tricky...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - if you think spelling's tricky, you should try [some awkward pronounciations](http://baetzler.de/humor/english_pronounciation.html)!

Comment: Some folks are just self-indulgent twits. *My* (embarrassingly many) mistakes are the result of rotten typing, poor proofreading and insufficient attention, and I would like to formally thank the OCD-inclined grammar-, usage- and spelling-police of Stack Exchange for their efforts.

Comment: @dmckee - damn, I can't find a single mistake in your comment! `:D`

Comment: Good, I've edited all but one of his questions of this year. Let's see if the message is clear. And if not, at least those look better. ;)

Comment: Great work @Bart.

Comment: Sorry to break the news to you, but if you can't tell a [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) from a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), you are not a "punctuation pedant". You are not even a punctuation noob. You are not a punctuation anything. Seriously.

Comment: @Pekka poor Canada! To defame them like that! Canadian English uses English spacing. And even in French, the space only goes before an exclamation mark, question mark, colon or semicolon. Though traditionally these are not necessarily full spaces. It also uses quarter-em spaces to offset quotation marks from the enclosed text. But never does a space go before a period or a comma. In fact I am not aware of a single language that uses spaces like that user does, so I am totally ready and willing to go on record as saying he has no idea what he's doing.

Comment: @Яeg thanks for the clarification!

Comment: 1) downvote one (better two) of "annoyingly lowercase" posts 2) wait for a day (better two) 3) return to the post, edit into shape, revert downvote 4) repeat... **[Down-votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/down-votes/info "explained in tag wiki excerpt"), "the community's way of telling peers that their content can be improved"**

Comment: I've fixed a few more, though I'm discovering they're often quite lengthy and contain many sub-questions! `:(`

Comment: A [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14637640/472495) from this user contains exactly the same errors. On the original post (see above) the OP has fought back, and _implied_ they have a disability that prevents them from following standard rules. However, he/she has outright refused to explain, so I'll report it to mod again.

Comment: Update - I flagged that latest example as having deliberately flouted polite requests from mods and non-mods, but the moderator declined it. The conversation history on the post in question (admittedly off-topic) has now gone completely, save Robert's link to here).

Comment: The particular user is active in the Android tag which is highly correlated with low quality. As Hans Passant has put it in [a blog comment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/): "Android is the toilet-bowl of Stack Overflow, only out-voted by the cesspool of the Facebook tag."

Comment: Ha ha, that made me laugh, @Peter! Yes, Android can be pretty woeful. This particular user improved for a while after feedback from various users, but of late he/she is going back to their bad old ways...

Comment: [It seems to have improved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73927441/how-to-get-current-wallpaper-on-android-13/74800134#74800134) (a rare case). Now at 1,434 answers. Though the original writing style points to India, not Israel as claimed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is an expectation that users of Stack Overflow treat the site like a professional resource.  For the most part, that means using proper spelling, grammar and punctuation.  It's an important enough issue to be baked into the system in several ways:

1. Automated low-quality posting blocks.
2. Automated low-quality posting bans.
3. Suspensions for repeatedly asking low-quality questions.

"This is my personal style" is not an acceptable excuse, nor is posting from a cell phone.  Find a real computer to post your questions with.

**Other Considerations**
Users whose first language is not English are already at a sharp disadvantage, which is why their close ratio is higher than most.  Like other rules, we do bend them occasionally if the OP manages to post questions that are so scintillating that we can overlook their bad grammer [sic].  We don't generally suspend users unless they demonstrate a persistent pattern of behavior that is harmful to the community.

**What to Do**
Flag one of their "stylish" posts with a custom explanation, describing what the problem is.  We will take the appropriate action.

Comment: _"... nor is posting from a cell phone. Find a real computer to post your questions with._" I wish I could upvote more than once for this alone.

Comment: As an aside, people seem to get away with a lot in the Android tag.  Android developers as a group... well, there's no nice way to say this, but... seem *less sophisticated,* as evidenced by the overall quality of posts in the Android tag; and folks participating in the Android tag seem to care less about things like proper spelling and grammar.

Comment: However, I might just downvote it now because of that Android comment. While it may be true, as someone who tries to use the correct spelling/grammar/punctuation, I resent being labeled because I also happen to develop Android apps!

Comment: @ryanOptini: [The person](http://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer) for whom this Meta post was created has posted literally [hundreds of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer?tab=questions) and answers with these kinds of grammatical errors, and nobody's complained about them *at all* until now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps they feel they ought to post from their Android phone for integrity's sake. I do very much wish mine had a `, because the workaround (copy-paste) is __not__ fun. Apart from the backticks, I find it very easy to keep up my usual standards on my phone, so it's not a good excuse anyway.

Comment: @AndrewC: The real question is, do we hold the Android tag to the same standard as other tags on Stack Overflow, when it is clear that the people in that community couldn't care less about it?  Note that the OP of this question [does not significantly participate](http://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer?tab=tags) in the Android tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes please on the consistent standards. Let's Make the Internet a Better Place.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Flagged as requested.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: as per a comment on the main thread, I think I am out of options. I flagged a new example of the user ignoring the community's wishes, and it was rejected, and the comments on the original thread in question have now been deleted. I suspect this will act as a green-lighting for deliberately poor writing standards from the user in question, so I will I think just have to keep my pedantry under control `:)`

Comment: It's difficult to solve a problem like this when it has gone on for so long, and the folks in the Android tag don't seem to care, so.

Comment: Yep, worth a try - thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: _"nor is posting from a cell phone"_ As someone who uses the StackExchange app an awful lot when not at a computer (for example, **right now**), this isn't even valid! It's perfectly possible to employ correct syntax on a phone. Sure, autocorrect can duck things up every now and then, and some things are impossible without a decent amount of effort (e.g. backticks aren't on the iOS keyboard) but just in terms of grammar, a phone isn't a barrier.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first off, unless they come out and directly say "I'm deliberately doing this" we don't know that they're deliberately doing it - so nothing can be done about it but editing the posts to fix them. Even if they admit it, it's not something that would warrant any kind of suspension.

If they, however, were actively *rolling back* edits that corrected grammar, spelling, etc - that would be an abuse of the editing system and *is* something that should be flagged so moderators can take appropriate action in warning and/or suspending them.

The simple fact is, some people just don't care enough to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, just like some don't care to hit the <kbd>'</kbd> key when appropriate. They've adapted themselves to an alternate way of typing that is irritating to some people.

Comment: At a certain level of repetition and after enough edits they simply *are* doing it deliberately. The system notifies them when their posts are edited, so it's not like they don't know that they are making work or haven't seen exemplars of what is expected.

Comment: @dmckee the last time I noticed that a post of mine was edited was about 6 months ago. It's possible to completely ignore edit notifications - if you want to make sure the OP notices, commenting is the way to go