# What can a non moderator do when he sees an interesting question mangled by bad english?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, etiquette, non-english-speakers

I would be somewhat interested to see this question answered but as it is now I doubt it. It's really terrible.

[How can I create an animated e-mail / SMS notification on an Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177022/how-can-i-notify-the-email)

Comment: Post it here and let me re-write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention, and leave a comment saying that it needs editing.

There's been [a request for a spelling and grammar flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/spelling-and-grammar-flag), but it's not accepted yet. It's not declined, either, though.

But for now the [official](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/spelling-and-grammar-flag/3082#3082) thing to do in this situation is to flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: selected as answer for including links

Comment: Yeah! Take that, TXI!

Comment: Moderators cannot do anything about bad grammar. If the post is so bad that is not possible to understand what said, then it should be flagged as "not an answer" (if it is an answer), or "not a real question (if it is question).

Answer (score 10):

Edit it and make it better! As of a few months ago, all users can edit questions. Users with <2k rep need to have their edits approved by users who do have edit privileges before the changes show up, though. On SO, two approvers are needed; on other sites, only one.

Comment: As time and SO features progress, I see a new game emerging: Necromancer Badge Hunting :)

Comment: Bah, like I need more MSO Necromancers. You're welcome to take some of my badges, if you can figure out how to unscrew them from the wall. (@Renesis)

Answer (score 8):

If you have enough rep to edit a CW post, go ahead and edit it.

If you have enough rep to edit a regular post, go ahead and edit it.

If you do not have enough rep to edit the post, flag it for moderator attention or leave a comment so that hopefully some others high rep users can take the time to clean it up.

Comment: Why don't we have a "Flag for Rich B to fix" button?

Comment: Isn't that what the #SOMafia channel is for?