# Is the following a good example of editing for grammar, or is it overboard?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, etiquette

This may very well get closed as a duplicate. I've read [Editing for broken english: Acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/editing-for-broken-english-acceptable), and I believe that my edits are OK, but I wanted some clarification. I want to make sure I'm not "abusing" my new found editing power.

I made significant changes to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865827/how-to-frequently-refresh-specific-web-page-using-php) because the original was so poorly written in my opinion that it was getting downvotes, when I can see a legitimate question here that shouldn't be downvoted. I tried as hard to maintain the style of the original question as best as I could. In this specific case, did I do a good job? If so I know I can use similar style in the future.

Comment: @Josh: Plus one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should users edit other users' posts to correct grammar and spelling problems?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-users-edit-other-users-posts-to-correct-grammar-and-spelling-problems)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=edit+grammar

Comment: @voyager: Yeah, it's a dupe of those... I just wanted to use a specific example, it's helpful to me. Sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: @Josh, it's ok, just that question 25 has a categorical yes to your question :)

Comment: @voyager: Well yes except when reading that it wasn't clear if that was correcting a few grammar mistakes, or if it included pretty much rewriting the whole damn thing, which is what I had to do in this case :-)

Comment: @Popular Demand: WHY DID YOU EDIT MY QUESTION!?!?!? ;-)

Comment: @Josh, I'm sure I don't have any idea what you're talking about.  I merely edited the tags, which is __completely__ different.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Sorry, it was a lame attempt at humor... because all too often people whine like that on SO. :-)

Comment: @Josh, I know, my second comment was an equally poor attempt at humor.  I don't like using smileys, so my deadpans don't work so well in writing sometimes.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I thought that might be the case, and I went ahead and ruined it for you! Sorry :-)

Comment: @Josh, no worries, mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's at least understandable now, so yes it's a good edit.

And I have to say it's good of you to solicit feedback on using your new editing power!

Any time you see a post where something is unclear, edit to make it clear, so long as you don't change the meaning of the post. That's all there is to it, really.

---

Posting here will probably result in further editing (<strike>I may have a go at it</strike> Done), but that's not a bad thing. I think it's pretty obvious that the user doesn't know much about how to accomplish what he's asking about, which was at least part of the issue with the original unclear question.

Comment: Thanks! And yes by all means feel free to edit further, in no way am I claiming to be a master of the English language :-)

Comment: Ooh, `[badge-request]`: Master of the English Language.  Alternate title/description/alt-text: "That is the kind of English up with which I will not put!"

Comment: I also find it helpful to see YOUR edits to MY edits, that helps me to know the best direction to go in the future. So thanks again!

Comment: LOL @Popular Demand

Comment: @pop: `[badge-request]`: Yoda

Comment: @Josh: You're welcome. If you're on SO a lot, there are a few habitual editors who do a good job (hopefully myself included) so there are plenty of examples.

Comment: @Jon: I am on SO a lot, I just can't get reputation nearly as fast as most! :-)

Comment: @Jon, actually, that quotation is attributed to Winston Churchill, not Yoda, though it could be apocryphal.  Supposedly, it was his answer to "How do you feel about people ending sentences with prepositions?"  (For some people, that joke will take longer than it will for others... when you're ready, though, click [I get it!](http://www.instantrimshot.com/).)