# Accept an edit that edited "noob" into conventional English?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, grammar

I was looking at an edit and they'd basically just fixed some spelling and grammar (although not thoroughly, there were still some issues, but that's beside the point). Anyway the asker said, in the question "I'm a relative noob to php" which the editor turned into "I'm a relative new to php" [sic]. So I could improve this to "I'm relatively new to PHP" or restore the original poster's language.

I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99295/174925) is a good one and agree with holding on to the original author's style -- so I would be inclined to restore "noob". Legit?

I haven't done a lot of editing, so I'm a little gun shy.

Comment: I think you're fine either way. I personally consider "noob" poor English though.

Comment: I edited that post by hitting Improve on the suggested edit. I took out the part where (twice) the poster called themselves a noob. It didn't need to be replaced with "new to", it needed to be removed. Meta talk about why you don't know what you're doing isn't helpful. The poster clearly stated "I don't know a lot about variables and arrays" and I left that in because it was relevant.

Comment: @KateGregory echoed exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: @KateGregory Yeah, they did go on quite a bit about their noobishness. Good call.

Comment: Kate's point is good, but imagine the part that she left, "I don't know a lot about variables and arrays" was actually "I'm a variables and arrays noob" and the edit was "I'm a variables and arrays new".

Comment: @KateGregory *Meta talk about why you don't know what you're doing isn't helpful* so why hasn't *I haven't done a lot of editing, so I'm a little gun shy.* been removed?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I can't speak for others, but for me things are different on Meta and personality is more appropiate, as is reason-for-asking. On SO, just-the-facts-ma'am - I don't care why you want to parse a string or that it will lead to a cure for world hunger, just show the string-parsing code and what's not working, and let people help with that.

Comment: *[Is newbie a synonym for beginner?](http://www.irosetta.com/questions/is-newbie-a-synonym-for-beginner)*

Answer (score 3):

Once again, we have a clear case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> I think this answer is a good one and agree with holding on to the original author's style -- so I would be inclined to restore "noob". Legit?

*You're talking* about about the edit and how it should be edited. When you *should be talking* about why it should be deleted.

I don't think I can find better words than [Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147247/kate-gregory) to explain this :

> I edited that post by hitting Improve on the suggested edit. I took out the part where (twice) the poster called themselves a noob. It didn't need to be replaced with "new to", it needed to be removed. Meta talk about why you don't know what you're doing isn't helpful. The poster clearly stated "I don't know a lot about variables and arrays" and I left that in because it was relevant.

Comment: Again, imagine the part Kate left: "I don't know a lot about variables and arrays" was actually "I'm a variables and arrays noob" and the edit was "I'm a variables and arrays new". This is my question.

Comment: @BenFlynn: Invalid edits are invalid.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In other words, revert, because their edit was not a good edit. Am I understanding you correctly? If so, that was my inclination too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: why "the edit" should be deleted?  a little unclear, I assume you mean "improved"