# Have an edit approval review page so we correct incorrect approvals and educate users

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

This is something that came out of recent discussions on acceptance of poor edits on this question [Pretty unnecessary use of italics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141089/if-it-is-in-italic-it-must-be-pretty).

It would be useful if there was a page that listed **all** recent edit approvals. In itself this would serve as an additional check (especially on sites that only require one approval vote) on edits so that any bad edits can be quickly corrected.

If in addition a couple of buttons were added that validated the approval ("This edit is OK", "This edit is not OK") then this could be extended to educate the approvers and those suggesting edits as well.

If the suggested edit gets N (where N > 1 and <=5?) "This edit is not OK" votes then this is treated as a rejection. The edit gets rolled back and the reject will count towards the 7 day time out for suggesting too many bad edits. This will hopefully help educate those suggesting bad edits.

The extra work needed would be to tally up the bad approvals from each user and use that somehow. For example, if M (where M > 5 and <=10?) of your approvals are subsequently rejected then your right to approve edits is suspended for 7 days. There would need to be information explaining this on the suggested edits page.

Obviously the same logic could be applied to rejected edits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/history

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: For me, that link just shows **my** history.  I believe Chis is proposing a page to show everybody's recent reviews.

Comment: Exactly, it's for educating other users.

Comment: @forsvarir that's probably because you have less than 10K rep, [here is how it looks like for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/48tFQ.png).

Comment: Working this into some sort of "Training" tab so that in addition to the auditing, future users could learn from actual examples of "common edit approval mistakes" through a quiz-type interface.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Answer (score 3):

**Reviewing isn't very fun** by itself, we (actually *I*) do it to make SO *better*. I am not sure that reviewing the reviewer will be a rewarding task.

Yet, not so many users come here (I mean on meta-SO) to understand **what is right or what is wrong** about syntax and rules on how it should be (and we often discuss about all this stuff here, for instance: [Is it acceptable to edit broken English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/editing-for-broken-english-acceptable) or even better [Suggested Edits add "Thanks in Advance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97136/suggested-edits-add-thanks-in-advance)).

Anyway, I really like jonsca's suggestion in the comments about a "Training tab".

We could double check the *first* reviews (don't really know how many would be needed though) to help users who recently earned the privilege of approving suggestions and **give them (us?) feedback** in a way or another (as there is no such MPs in SO).

Comment: Like the idea of limiting to "first" reviews - though it would perhaps have to be the "first 20" (or similar number)

Comment: And probably reviews from reviewers with extreme accept or reject rates. If somebody rejects 90% of suggested edits, or accepts 99%, I think somebody should have a look at their decisions.

Comment: Mostly agree - Having a **unique** reference on meta would help to. At the moment, reviewing guidelines (Hi Thanks, code formatting, italic etc.) are spread across numerous posts.