# Twice approved suggested edit, eventually rejected

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Require more than two coinciding votes to approve/reject a suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142954/require-more-than-two-coinciding-votes-to-approve-reject-a-suggested-edit)

I have a case of a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/830483), approved by two reviewer, but eventually rejected.
How may this happen?

[image]

**Edit**

When has the update been released?

Comment: explained in this answer: [Require more than two coinciding votes to approve/reject a suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151636/165773) "The number of reviews required to accept/reject suggested edits has been increased to two Network wide (versus 1 before) and three on Stack Overflow. (versus 2 before)..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango/151586#151586), suggested edits on Stack Overflow are now approved or rejected by a best-of-five decision, so three consenting votes are needed. On the other sites, previously only one vote was needed, now two are needed.

So with two approve votes, the suggestion was not yet accepted, and an edit by the OP while the suggestion was pending would automatically cause a rejection.

Comment: That does not explain the apparently "mysterious" rejection though. Although I think we might have a simple "grace period" edit by the OP causing the rejection. Speculation though.

Comment: Ah, true, I'll add that.

Comment: See [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit/141872#141872) where I reached the same conclusion.