# Can we have more easily accessible stats and clearer guidelines for suggested edit reviewers?

Tags: feature-request, support, rejected-edits

I recently rediscovered my Suggested Edit stats via:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/{userid}/{username}?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
```

On reviewing a few, I realised that not all of the Rejections that I had received were justified. Out of them, one stood out particularly, because, where my Edit was rejected, an exact edit was approved!

The revision in question is:

- My Rejected Edit:
  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/220888
- Other Accepted Edit:
  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11967017/revisions

I propose a much clearer access to the Suggested Edit stats, maybe similar to the Review Flags stats. This enables us to easily keep track of which edits were not acceptable, and in this process learn!

Learn is exactly what I did from all the rejections I saw, but until recently I was oblivious to most of them.

Also, a higher weightage must be required to reject suggestions, maybe once an Editor passes a certain number of successful edits.

Is this something that has been addressed in the overhaul of the review system? Another question on similar lines comes to mind:

[Require more than two coinciding votes to approve/reject a suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142954/require-more-than-two-coinciding-votes-to-approve-reject-a-suggested-edit)

I hope this is not misunderstood as a pet-peeve! I am not looking to get my 2 rep, I am hoping for a change :)

Answer (score 1):

Your edit to the post was rejected by the OP of the post (apparently he didn't like the change). In this case his vote is binding and no other people need to vote.

Currently you need the majority of five people to approve a suggested edit. (3 votes to be approved)

Comment: Makes sense :) But I still propose Clarity!

Comment: @bPratik Fair enough.