# Automatically recognize and remove "thanks"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, automatic-edits, thanks, regex

There is a regex that should automatically remove all greetings from the top of posts. It does its job very well:

```
^                 # begins at start of body
\s*               # possible spaces
(
hii?(?![a-z])|    # any of these greeting words
hello|
h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|
dear|
greetings|
hai|
guys|
howdy|
h(i|e)ya|
hola
)
.*?               # followed by anything, up to...
(
[.,;!-]+          # one or more bits of punctuation
\s*               # possible spaces
|
(\r?\n)+          # one or more newlines
)
```

---

---

I propose we add one for "thanks" and related endings. Here is my draft:

```
\s*
(
(and\s*)?(\+\s*)?(with\s*)?
(so\s*)?(many\s*)?(mu?ch\s*)?
(lots\s*(of\s*)?)?
((tha?nk)|(thx)|(thnx)|regard)s?\s*
(you\s*)?
(in adva?nced?\s*)?
((a\s*)?lots?\s*)?
(((very\s*)|(so\s*))?mu?ch\s*)?
((and\s*)?(\+\s)?regards?\s*)?
[\.\!]*\s*
([\:\;]\s*[\-\~\=]*\s*[\)\]\}\>D3]+)* #smilies :) :D ;-3 etc.
[\.\!]*\s*
)
$
```

I am sure there could be many improvements, but it's a start. And it will save many an editor's time.

And because I couldn't resist the irony:

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Automatically edit out TIA/Thanks In Advance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148695/182513) and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Will this erase some or all of the following? Here is my code: [newline] <begin code block>`MyString = thanks`

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/212673

Comment: @GeorgeWBush That's a **very** rare if not impossible case in which the code would have to end at the very end and the code would be setting a variable to "thanks" for some reason. Also in most programming languages you would need single or double quote around it. @ your second comment Err... that's what I put in my question

Comment: In my example, "thanks" would also be a variable name. It's not impossible, but is is extremely rare. I posed it because I was trying to poke holes in your regex. Is it worth breaking 1 honest codeblock in order to auto-remove 1 million superfluous signatures? Code blocks and block quotes should probably be immune

Comment: @GeorgeWBush Yes. Yes, of course it is. Who names their variables "thanks," anyway? I'll search code for "thanks" and see what pops up :P

Comment: Apparently we get many "Thanks"s in code instead of plaintext: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588746/how-to-remove-badge-notification-symbol-from-app-icon-in-iphone (I found a bunch with search: `code:thanks`)

Comment: **I agree but disagree. Some may think it's *impolite* not to say that.** What I hate is when someone **gains reputation for removing "Thanks."** Do you get promotions at jobs for removing "Thanks" in a coworker's email when replying? People that do it to me the most usually cannot gain from edits anymore, but it is very possible to gain rep just for removing a greeting (which doesn't really add to the answer/make it easier to understand). Like someone else said on another post, *a three letter "Hi," isn't going to reduce the quality of the post and prevent people from vising: it's polite.*

Comment: Is there nothing better to work on or improve on StackExchange, than to remove people for thanking each other??! What has this world come to :-O hahah

Comment: +1 simply for `d?` in `adva?nce?d`. That drives me nuts. However, I predict this could have a high rate of failure or false positives, perhaps too much to be worth it.

Answer (score 8):

I think that having this implemented would make a great start on improving the professional appearance of questions on every Stack Exchange site.

The Tour of every site already says that there should be no chit chat, and I think unnecessary thanks are an example of chit chat.

A Meta Stack Overflow Q&A that resonates with me is [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Comment: The "remove greetings" filter has [had](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304996/should-the-word-hay-not-be-deleted-at-the-beginning-of-posts-especially-on-sp#comment991423_304996) [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268215/answers-dont-like-hair-i-e-hair-at-the-beginning-of-an-answer-is-automatic).  I'm sure a thanks-removing filter will find new and exciting ways to mangle posts.