# Answers don't like hair (i.e., "hair" at the beginning of an answer is automatically deleted)

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, automatic-edits, noise-reduction

> [image: Edits with hair don't stick]

As you can see I made an edit but it won't stick and gets deleted right away; another user with 20k rep also tried to make the same edit with no luck.

[This is the answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/28090/9446) where it happened. Also I have copied it to the answers in this question; feel free to try and edit it by adding `Hair,` to the front.

Comment: Probably caused by the [auto salutations removal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/209357).

Comment: Off the top of my head, pretty sure this is powered by a regex, so fixing this will potentially be a ... ⌐■_■ ... hairy situation.

Answer (score 34):

Hair,

You can get a temporary workaround by adding an invisible comment using `<!-- -->` at the beginning of your answer. Then you can add 'Hair' after it. I agree though that this needs to be fixed.

Comment: Making it bold also works.

Comment: or adding `<img></img>` before

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, but you can see that. This is invisible.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236615/152859), adding unicode character "Zero Width Space" also works. I'll post a comment consisting only of those so it's easier to copy, let me try.. oh, not making it easier to copy. Ways to type this character are described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/389087/how-to-type-zero-width-space-character-u200b-on-a-laptop-keyboard). :)

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @ShadowWizard and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/156640/how-can-i-type-u200b-character?lq=1) if you're not using a laptop keyboard, ie alt08203

Comment: @ShadowWizard - surely you meant bald*=

Answer (score 20):

We have performed a Hair removal removal.

Hair is no longer trimmed, cut, stripped, or buzzed.

Comment: Is there any hope that [Jeff Atwood's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989) will be updated to include the new regex?

Comment: I was a bit confused about whether this is a joke post until I went to geoff's profile and saw he was a staff.

Answer (score 15):

Considering the [regex used seems to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/239016):

```
^                 # begins at start of body
\s*               # possible spaces
# any of these greetings
(hii?(?![a-z])|hello|h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|dear|greetings|hai|guys|howdy|h(i|e)ya|hola)
.*?               # followed by anything, up to...
(
   [.,;!-]+       # one or more bits of punctuation
   \s*            # possible spaces
|                 # or
   (\r?\n)+       # one or more newlines
)
```

Replacing the `.*?` by something that matches less should fix it. My suggestions:

- `(\W.*?)?` makes sure that any of the bad words is followed by a non-word character before matching anything else
- `\b.*?` makes sure we're at a word boundary before matching the rest

Putting it together and removing superfluous bits

```
^                 # begins at start of body
\s*               # possible spaces
# any of the following greetings
(h[ai]i?|hello|h[eai]ya?|dear|greetings|hai|guys|howdy|hola)
\b                # word boundary, to not match words that begin with a bad word
.*?               # followed by anything, up to...
(
   [.,;!-]+       # one or more bits of punctuation
   \s*            # possible spaces
|                 # or
   [\r\n]+        # one or more newlines
)
```

Of course, you should check this against your unit tests. You *do* use unit tests, don't you?

And this would still match a useful answer on [workplace.se] that reads

> Greetings should be exchanged as soon as you enter the room for your interview.

or

> Dear or howdy is much too informal for a letter to a supplier.

or, over on [musicfans.se]

> Guys 'n' Dolls is probably the band you're looking for.

So I agree that a pop-up alerting the user might be better.

Comment: SE's unit test is MSE.

Answer (score 12):

The icy ball form of precipitation - induce the same bug.

The regex is attempting to defeat an initial "hai" (as in [o hai](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=o+hai&tbm=isch)), but it is overzealous.

The [regex being](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/260841):

```
^                 # begins at start of body
\s*               # possible spaces
(
hii?(?![a-z])|    # any of these greeting words
hello|
h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|
dear|
greetings|
hai|
guys|
howdy|
h(i|e)ya|
hola
)
.*?               # followed by anything, up to...
(
[.,;!-]+          # one or more bits of punctuation
\s*               # possible spaces
|
(\r?\n)+          # one or more newlines
)
```

Comment: Running that regex against `/usr/share/dict/words`, the only problematic entry is `hai`, which matches a variety of "hail" and "hair" words (plus "Haiti" and "Haitian").  `dear` matches a few, but they're all uncommon or are derivatives of "dear" such as "dearest".  Nothing else generates false positives.

Comment: Running it against the list of article titles on Wikipedia, `hai` is again the main problem one, although `hola` generates a fair few false positives as well.  `dear` and `hello` generate a bunch of hits, but they're almost all titles in the form of greetings, except for variations on "Dearborn".

Comment: How about `hay`, in a hypothetical answer on the bio stack, on what to feed cows?

Comment: Hay una problema with banning "hay" for [the Spanish site](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/) too, probably

Comment: The regex should not modify the post text but just display a popup saying "Please don't include salutations" or something alike. This would 1) educate the user, and 2) allow for legitimate word usage in case of false positive.

Comment: looool do people _really_ try to start posts with "hai"???? (wow that regex is terrible... at least chuck in a `\b` for goodness's sake!!!)