# Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, languages, quality-filter, signatures

Saludos.

^^^ as you see, I just said hello in Spanish and nothing happened, despite "Saludos" means "**greetings**" in Spanish.

In Spanish Stack Exchange [we noticed](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2760/1674) that a post cannot start with something as normal as "**Hay**", which in English can be considered a greeting, but in Spanish just means "**there are**" and seems to be a perfectly valid word to start a post with :)

All of this comes from the [automatic removal of salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/209901) that Stack Exchange has in place, which performs some checks and removes those strings that match this regex:

> ```
> ^                 # begins at start of body
> \s*               # possible spaces
> (
> hii?(?![a-z])|    # any of these greeting words
> hello|
> h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|
> dear|
> greetings|
> hai|
> guys|
> howdy|
> h(i|e)ya|
> hola
> )
> .*?               # followed by anything, up to...
> (
> [.,;!-]+          # one or more bits of punctuation
> \s*               # possible spaces
> |
> (\r?\n)+          # one or more newlines
> )
> ```

At the same time, we seem to somehow know if a post is in English or not by using the [*English threshold*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/209901).

All of this taken into consideration, could we have language specific automatic removal of salutations so clear greetings in other languages are removed, while perfectly valid non-greeting words are preserved? Of course, I mean this for the languages that currently have a site.

Comment: Closely related: [Should the word "hay" not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially in the Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards while they are quite connected (the OP of the other question in fact [previously asked in Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2760/1674) and I answered him) I don't think they are exact duplicates.. Mine is a feature request to have a broad implementation throughout the network. The other question is very specific about a specific greeting.

Comment: @fedorqui We can certainly do this! Let's get a list of Spanish words together for exclusion and we can go from there. Would you like to start that list?

Comment: @JuanM nice! I have brought this to a Spanish.SE chat and we currently have several items. [See the list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42059786#42059786).

Comment: Not a duplicate at all, used hammer to clear pending close votes.

Answer (score 10):

The following list of words are now on the exclusion list:

- Saludos
- Hola
- Queridos
- Gracias
- Estimados
- Buen( o | a ) s
- Que tal

Comment: `Buen(o|a|s)` You sure *Buens* is a word? Shouldn't it be `Buen(o|a)s?`?

Comment: You're right, I typed it wrong above but it's correct in the system.

Comment: You may want to add `Obrigados` as well (aunque no es espanol).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great news @JuanM! Probably better `querid(o|a)s?` so the _s_ is optional and the same for `estimad(o|a)s?`.

Comment: In fact we see some _buen día_, ([sample](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/137900/83)), so `Buen(o|a)?s?` would also help.

Comment: Could we also add `Buen día`? It occurs quite often: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/153605/83

Comment: @fedorqui I'll have that added as well!

Comment: Thanks, Juan! Let us know when it is live