# Your community’s current problems, findings, and initiatives

Tags: discussion, international-sites

Remember how you started programming? I’d bet that when many of you were kids who played with graphic editors after school and at some point decided to find out what the difference between `.img` and `.exe` files was. As a result, you installed Turbo Pascal and instead of working with funny pictures, you tried to add something to the downloaded “Hello World.” The typical programming approach at that stage looked like this: "How to increase a counter? - Copy the line with the counter a few times!" Findings like functions or a debugger were no less important than the Theory of Relativity.

Also, do you remember when you made the most progress? Probably, when you met a peer as interested in programming as you. It’s likely that during the first month of working together, your knowledge increased more than in the previous year, when you had studied programming alone.

It appears that our international communities are growing and following the same scenario. Consider this:

- All international communities start with standard settings on the site.
- Each community faces similar problems that other international communities face at some stage.
- At some point, some of the problems become critical.
- The community, after contributing a lot of time and effort, finds solutions to the critical problems one by one.
- All other international communities do not benefit from those solutions because they do not know what happens on other sites and...
- ...they continue to suffer, until the same problems become very critical on their sites as well.

Why not to work together?

## The problem

International communities face the same problems again and again, but being isolated, they don’t know that their problems have often been solved elsewhere.

### Two examples

#### (1) Site settings

At some point, on Stack Overflow in Russian we had gotten a lot of questions with greetings. Some users began to edit the questions, which resulted in a large number of edits in the review queue. Reviewers became angry at the editors and the community began discussing what to do with these edits, whether it was necessary to edit old questions at all, etc. We began digging and it turned out that on the site there is a setting that configures the engine to remove greetings automatically when a question gets posted. Kind of the same story with the “thank-you” like comments.

#### (2) Initiatives

The company is constantly improving the site, including the user interface. Sometimes this leads to a loss in translation. The situation is very annoying and all the international communities suffered from it until [g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4?tab=profile) created [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/), which helps to avoid losing translations in the most common cases. Unfortunately, traducir.win is not used by all communities which results in some communities still losing translations.

## Proposed solution

I think the international communities can be more effective if we move forward together. The first step towards joint development is to start sharing our problems, findings, and initiatives with all international communities.

#### The essence of the approach

In the context “[Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/274323)”, it would be great to keep a list of each community’s current problems, findings (aka “solved problems”) and initiatives on MSE. For example, [in the form presented in the wiki answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317206/274323).

If you have any ideas about the the initiative, please share it!

At the same time, do not hesitate to add your community’s current problems, findings, and initiatives to the list. Even if we change the process based on feedback, the list will help us see the actual situation.

---

### Related:

- Spanish: [Los problemas, hallazgos e iniciativas actuales de la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/324) (thanks to [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi))
- Portuguese: [Os problemas atuais, as descobertas e as iniciativas da sua comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7407/5878) (thanks to [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss))
- Japanese: [各コミュニティが抱える問題や気づき、機能提案をまとめてみませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2834/2767) (thanks to [aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki))

Comment: Are there any ways or movements to make the individual sites' findings understandable for the other sites, which don't speak the languages of each other (and often aren't too prone for English as a mediator language either, hence their existence)? I don't know how much Portuguese speakers are going to take from these links to Russian meta posts.

Comment: If you expect this question to be edited by the community, consider making it community wiki, no?

Comment: Great initiative! Regarding the salutations problem, I opened a debate in Meta.SE: [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125/209901). It lead to have some Spanish words also listed as salutations, but I never got feedback on exactly which ones are there now.

Comment: It would also be interesting to check the _Audit reviews_ status. We have been asking for them in SOes for years, while SOpt has had it for many years now.

Comment: @rene I assumed the contributions would rather be answer. This...would make quite a bit more sense than extending the question by answers. But I might be misunderstanding this.

Comment: @rene I agree with you that the list should be presented as a wiki post. If we made the question wiki, this would make all answers wiki as well, which I do not want. At the same time it would be cool if the list appears on international metas. I'd suggest to keep it as it is for a few days and then move it to a dedicated answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau It's a very interesting question! And my answer is... I do not know. I see a big issue that we do not reuse positive experience between communities.  This is an attempt to address the problem. I definitely sure that an international site user will tell us how to improve the suggested approach.

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you! Please add all initiatives to the list. If the SOes community agrees that it needs something, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @Nicolas maybe better make this CW so it's easier to edit?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, let's do that.

Comment: No wait.. didn't mean answer which is CW, meant you can make the question itself CW, if you plan others to edit it directly. (Ordinary users can't make a question CW but you can do it with the diamond, probably under some mod menu.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's what exactly do I mean: compile the list together. It seems to me that the initial proposal as well as feedback should have authors.

Answer (score 12):

## List of international communities' current problems, findings, and initiatives

#### Initiatives

- *traducir.win*

  - Es: [Traduciendo el sitio… Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/10).
  - Ja: [サイトを翻訳するための新ツールの提案: Traducir](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2750/78).
  - Ru: [Мы переходим на Traducir.win для перевода интерфейса сайта!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/6)
  - Pt: [Estamos mudando para o Traducir.win para as traduções da interface](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7515/17539)
- *Question associations*

  - Ru: [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)
  - Es: [Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/83) (a set of the most viewed questions in SO with a link to its related one in SOes; to do: link them somehow from SO to SOes for users with ES settings in their browser), [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/10)
- How to make a decision based on community's feedback.

  - Es: [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/65)
- Improving the translations on the Help Center articles by doing pull requests to a repo.

  - Es: [Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del “Centro de Ayuda” y de “Privilegios”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/83). Articles with some flaws were community-wiki translated and then a pull request was done to a repo of a developer, so he pushed to the Stack Overflow en español site.
- The "Translate from English" help center article

  - Es: [¿Debería traducir preguntas del inglés al español?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
  - Ru: [Следует ли переводить сообщения с английского языка на русский?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
  - Ja: [英語版サイトの質問や回答を、日本語に翻訳しても良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
  - Pt: [Central de Ajuda: Posso traduzir conteúdo de outro site no SOpt? Como?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7678/17539)
- Compile list of basic tips on how to use the site

  - Ru: [Подсказки о механиках работы Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/6)
  - Es: [Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/10)
- Community banners

  - Ru: [Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/6)
  - Ja: [オリジナルバナー作成について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2915/78)
- Key values of the community

  - Ja: [スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版で大切にしたい価値観とは](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2974/78)
  - Es: [Los valores fundamentales de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4031/10)
  - Ru: [Ключевые ценности сообщества Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8891/6)
  - Pt: [Os valores do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7742/5878)
- What to do with sites that contain of only machine translated content from Stack Overflow in English

  - Ru: [Меньше спама, больше полезных знаний о программировании: как бороться с машинными переводами в поисковой выдаче](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8722/6)

#### Findings

- *[Removing salutations automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/274323)*

  - [Should the word “hay” not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially on Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996)
  - [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125)
  - Ru: [Автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/6)
- *Automatically delete a comment when a user flags it as no longer needed*

  - Ru: [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6).
- *Warnings on question and answers*

  - Es: [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/324)
- Enabling review audits

  - Es: [Ya nos graduamos, habiliten los audits en las colas de revision](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2572/15301)
- Changing the name of the "Strunk & White" badge for something ES-specific

  - Es: [Cambiemos el nombre de la medalla “Strunk & White” por algo más reconocible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2077/83)
- Alert before posting a question if it's written in English

  - Es: [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83)
    <sub>based on [this answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325866/1983854) to Meta SO's [*False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325865/1983854).</sub>
  - Ja: [英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/19110)
  - Pt: [Que tal um alerta para perguntas em outro idiomas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7741/5878)
- Community promotion adds.

  - Es: [¿Podemos tener anuncios de promoción de la comunidad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1140/83) --> [2017 edition](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/83)

#### Current problems

- Add a validation for questions that have only code

  - Es: [Añadamos una alerta en preguntas que son solo código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3491/a%c3%b1adamos-una-alerta-en-preguntas-que-son-solo-c%c3%b3digo)
  - Pt: [Que tal um alerta para perguntas com apenas código?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7735)
- Having the Triage review queue

  - Es: [Instauremos una cola de revisión “triaje” para que solo las preguntas con cierto nivel entren en la página de inicio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200/83) (let's have the Triage review queue)
- Having posters for universities and learning centers.

  - Es: [Proposed by the CM](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1314/83), not clear how to get them.
- [CR] [A notification need to be sent when someone adds a new help center article or edits existing one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318782/289691).

Comment: @nekketsuuu regarding _Alert before posting a question if it's written in other languages_ in SOes we have it: [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83). Basically, it checks for some words in the title and the body and, if they match, it prompts an alert. I added a link to it in the _Findings_ section of this answer.

Comment: @fedorqui: "Having posters for universities and learning centers. Proposed by the CM, but never implemented." `Never implemented` is wrong. I received posters from Juan and posted them on a couple of universities.

Comment: @Rubén good one. I asked for them on a Skype conversation with Juan and was told that I would get some, but never received those. You could share them in Meta SOes so we do not depend on emails.

Comment: We are looking for art for all sites :) I'll share everything we find. I remember that we had posters at least for SOru and SOes, but it was many moons ago. Let see what we find.

Comment: @fedorqui: I don't have the digital files. Juan bring the posters to the meetup that we had on Monterrey two years ago.

Comment: I checked again: I mentioned this issue of the posts since it appears in the list of [goals for 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1314/83) without the check mark of being completed.