# The Terminal: a chat room for international site users

Tags: discussion, chat, international-sites

[image]

One of the key factors of [our success](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/274323) is effective communication. I am glad to introduce a chat room “[The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)”. It’s a place for international site users and anyone else who is passionate about our communities.  In creating the chat room I would like to improve:

1. *Communication between communities*. I think we need to create a place where international communities can [discuss their day-to-day issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323) and getting to know each other in a fast and informal way.
2. *Understanding what you need*. The best way to understand what a community needs is to listen to its users. It seems to me I’m missing something that is happening on international metas. If you think that, I as an employee need to take a look at something on your meta, please tell me about it in the chat room.
3. *On time assistance*. I feel bad that international community users cannot talk in chat to someone from the company when they need help with the site. Ping me in the chat room whenever you need any assistance.

Please, [join the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)! Meet other international folks and tell me how can I help you!

**The post on international metas**

- [La Terminal: Un medio de discutir para usuarios internacionales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3714/) (thanks to [Robert Columbia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/336163/robert-columbia))
- [The Terminal: uma sala de chat para usuários dos sites internacionais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7429/the-terminal-uma-sala-de-chat-para-usu%C3%A1rios-dos-sites-internacionais) (thanks to [hkotsubo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/401803/hkotsubo))

Comment: I would appreciate translations! Please help me share the link with all our international site users!

Comment: International site users in this context refers only to users of spanish, portugese and russian SO, right?

Comment: @Magisch [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) too. (It has no Stack Overflow in its name unlike the other three, so can't be easily found.)

Comment: @Magisch I think we can add [Russian language](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) to the international site list as well.

Comment: I've translated to portuguese and posted in [SOpt.meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7429/112052) (and did a suggested edit in your post, adding the link). One suggestion: tell what languages will be used in the chat room. After entering the room we can see it's english (and it seems to be the "obvious" choice), but anyway, that could be in the post, just to make it more "official" and avoid anyone trying to use another language by mistake.

Comment: @hkotsubo Thank you a lot for translating it! I've pinned [the rules directly in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47288083#47288083), including one about the language (answer: you can use any language). It seems that if we keep rules in the chat it's easy to find them.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Spanish version:

Un factor esencial de [nuestro éxito](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/274323) es la comunicación efectiva. Tengo el gusto de presentar una sala nueva de chat que se llama "[The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)" ("La Terminal"). La Terminal será un medio para usuarios internacionales y cualquier otra persona que tienen fervor hacia nuestras comunidades. Con la creación de la sala de chat me gustaría mejorar:

1. *Comunicación entre comunidades*. Creo que debemos crear un medio donde las comunidades internacionales puedan [discutir sus problemas cotidianos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323) y conocerse mutuamente de una manera rápida e informal.
2. *Comprender lo que necesitan Uds.*. La mejor manera de comprender lo que necesita una comunidad es escuchar a sus usuarios. Me parece que me estoy perdiendo algo en las metas internacionales. Si creen eso, yo, como empleado, necesito ver algo en tu meta, por favor, dímelo en el chat.
3. *Ayuda puntual*. Me siento mal de que los usuarios internacional  de la comunidad no puedan hablar por chat con alguien de la compañía cuando necesitan ayuda con el sitio. Háganme un ping en la sala de chat cuando necesiten ayuda.

¡Por favor [únanse al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)! ¡Conozcan a personas internacionales y díganme como puedo ayudarles!

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind to post it on [MSOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @Nicolas Sure, no problem.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky done: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3714/el-terminal-un-medio-de-discutir-para-usuarios-internationales

Comment: Thank you! I've added a link to the MSOes in the post!