# Does Stack Exchange remove Ha! from my answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, automatic-edits

I just began [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51489739/946226) with

> Ha, I just ran into this myself!

but it would come out as

> I just ran into this myself!

and an edit would not help.

Now I see how that beginning of an answer is not strictly adding to its content value, but it seems like it does not hurt and – especially with regard to the recent push for more friendliness on SE – make the user experience a bit more … natural. Maybe the software is a bit too eager with manual editing of posts?

Comment: [Regex censoring considered harmful](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/), [part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268215/answers-dont-like-hair-i-e-hair-at-the-beginning-of-an-answer-is-automatic) the [third](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304996/should-the-word-hay-not-be-deleted-at-the-beginning-of-posts-especially-on-sp?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: [Jeff Atwood on 2011-06-06: *"We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered."*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989). Perhaps "ha" is considered a variation of "hai" or "hay"?

Comment: I have seen https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/215349 but it does not include `ha`, and `ha` is not a greeting or salutation, I’d say.

Comment: That list has probably been updated since then, based on how people have tried to circumvent it, e.g. by removing the last letter from "hai" or "hay".

Answer (score 4):

You seem already to have provided evidence that "Ha, " is being removed.

I don't know what came next in your answer but I would always prefer to see an answer begin with:

```
<start of answer meat>
```

rather than:

```
Ha, I just ran into this myself!
<start of answer meat>
```

To me "Ha, " is definitely chit chat, and all of "Ha, I just ran into this myself!" may be too.

When I visit an answer, the sooner the answerer starts providing the meat of the answer, the sooner I can decide whether the answer provided will answer the question that I came looking for an answer to.  I assume that an answerer will usually be familiar with the issue of a question that they are answering, so learning that that had run into it recently will normally add little.