# Add thanks as unnecessary chit chat to Expected Behavior page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, behavior

I think a large part of each Stack Exchange site's community considers terms like "Thanks", "Thanks in advance", "Much appreciated", "Tks", "Thx", "Hope it helps", etc to be chit chat and distracting in questions and answers.

A Meta Stack Overflow Q&A that supports my view is [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) and the [Expected Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) page of each site already says:

> **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
> which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional
> signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the
> questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your
> interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

I think this should be tweaked to say:

> **Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks and other chit chat.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
> which links directly back to your user page.  Your user page belongs
> to you, so fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff
> you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!
>
> Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and like other chit chat
> should not be included.
>
> If you use signatures, taglines, greetings, thanks or other chit chat,
> it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.

I think doing this would help eliminate much chit chat at its source, reduce bumps triggered by editing them out, and improve the professional appearance of questions and answers on every Stack Exchange site.  Editing "thanks, etc" out, as part of broader edits, is supported at [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

A feature request to [Automatically recognize and remove "thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169858/automatically-recognize-and-remove-thanks) from 8 years ago has not been implemented, and I think the above suggestion could go a long way towards to making it unnecessary.

Comment: The [Help Center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) has been updated with the revised text from above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by @JuanM:

> The [Help Center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) has been updated with the revised text from above.

I also checked a per-site [Expected Behavior](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) page and the text was present there too.