# Having 'nice' text - are we too strict?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, behavior, be-nice-policy

I recently posted an answer and also have posted questions as well with text like

1. "Thanks for your help"
2. "I hope this helps you"
3. "I hope this is helpful"

These types of text have been removed the last one cited.

```
"Stack Overflow is like an encyclopedia, so we prefer to omit these types of phrases. It is assumed that everyone here is trying to be helpful."
```

It is assumed? If you go into a shop and ask for help - and you don't you say thanks or sorry if you knock over a drink in a pub say - then doesn't that come off as well.

People on the internet do comment on the poor behaviour of some people on the site and saying thanks/that's helpful as well as votes are a way of showing that the site is a friendly place open to all. Votes up and down help the computer work out the good from bad answers. "Thanks", "sorry" and "I hope this helps", helps users work out the bad users from the good.

Text around the site backs this up.

```
Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person
```

(is the text for asking a question)
I'm asking the question to another person. So a good question has a lot of information, but also a level of kindness in the text. Equally responses would be similar. Informative with a nice ending as well.

I get that we want basically a repository of questions and answers - but 'nice comments' around the subject are well just good manners and something we should promote not just remove out of hand.

I guess at the end of day, I'm asking for the guidelines to be updated and for a little more leniency in policy/procedures.

Comment: Stack Exchange specifically strives for everything to be as focused on the topic as possible. We say "thank you for your answer, it was really helpful" through voting it up, and, if it's an answer to your own question, accepting it. Additionally, if you want to reward an above and beyond answer, you can offer bounties. Take a read of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/355458) for more

Comment: Thanks for the link to the question - I guess I'll point to this answer
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2965/1014726
and most seem to be ok with that.

Comment: I reading an answer here - plenty of Thanks Going on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514750/can-not-add-newtonsoft-json-linq-jproperty-to-newtonsoft-json-linq-jarray
In the comments.

Comment: I've flagged that one already, it will be gone shortly.

Comment: @RichardHousham Plenty of thanks, but also plenty of _other_ content, and we can't edit comments. As for: *"I guess I'll point to this answer meta.stackexchange.com/a/2965 and most seem to be ok with that."* - Sure, but _more_ people are fine with https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021... i.e., just removing them

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363568/add-thanks-as-unnecessary-chit-chat-to-expected-behavior-page

Comment: Imagine what Wikipedia would be like if its articles didn't end with "Thanks for reading this article, have a nice day!". Oh, wait...

Comment: Perhaps a way to _link_ questions/answers to a single, monolithic "gratitude" or appreciation "question", where all users can post "thanks"-like comments for the community at large, but just in _one place_ as opposed to polluting up all the other questions/answers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, we're not too strict.

The rest of the Internet went overboard with their fake politeness.

The questions and answers here are not for you, specifically. They are for the many visitors who follow.

Those visitors are looking for information/answers to solve a problem/question they have. They might have to wade through 20 pages of Google results. Page after page they read: *Good morning/evening*, all kinds of contextual noise, followed by endless greetings and useless salutations—but no actual answer. And on to the next one: 4 pages of *I've this problem too* (glad I'm not alone), blah blah, sigh. Next.

Our Question and Answer model attempts to solve the above problem. We want to get rid of the endless noise, the chit chat, the nonsense that takes up space without adding value. Keep in mind that we're not a Social Network. We're not here for the users; we're here for the content.

We're nice in Chat and professional in our exchanges, but, above all, **we optimize for knowledge sharing towards a future generation**. We expect them to value our strictly-curated high-density content without the distractions found on so many other sites.

Yes, that is different from Reddit, Quora, YouTube, Twitter, and traditional forums. But we are different by design, and it brought us where we are now. Use votes to show your thanks for valuable content. We understand and appreciate those votes. We don't need comments, taglines, or salutations. The other sites can have them all.

Comment: Imagine if we did not clean up salutations from posts... first thing anyone would read from 2020 content would be "happy quarantine, y'all"...