# Mass-editing existing answers with a similar pattern

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, suggested-edits

There is a torrent of suggested edits on the StackOverflow review queue from a single user, who apparently searches for the line `pain in the ass` and modifies it to something "non-explicit".

Most of this suggestions get rejected, but it resises two questions:

1. Is it appropriate to edit answers in such a way?
2. Is `pain in the ass` really too explicit for SO?

p.s. I've checked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148724/mass-edits-by-new-users) question, but I believe the situation is a bit different - suggested edits are much more trivial in this case, and user is not really new.

Comment: I usually leave a comment for the user on a post they edited (You can use @user to notify an editor, even though the auto-complete won't work) and nicely point them to this question: [Does Stack Exchange have an official stance on users doing a large number of trivial edits to old questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165878/158605). I understand that usually users just want to help, and typically don't know that that sort of trivial "help" isn't wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't call it overly offensive.  That most of the suggestions are getting rejected means that they suggested edit system is working, especially if it's the only edit the user is making (too trivial).

Hopefully the user gets the message eventually, but if it's a hassle to scrub these, and you don't want to out the user here, flag one of the answers that the user edited, using the Custom Description option, and we will review it.

Users without editing privileges should probably refrain from suggesting edits like this; it takes time to review such edits, and we'd rather spend such time on more substantial edit suggestions.

Comment: thanks, I've just flagged one of the edited answers