# Reviewer education

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

A reviewer has chosen to reject the following edit that I have made to the saw iv tag wiki

https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2835

They gave the reason

> "Two edits two the same tag."

I imagine that this person does not realise that there is a tag excerpt and a tag wiki page, I think that perhaps they have seen the similarity between the tag except and the tag wiki and become confused, is there any way to deal with a situation like this?

I understand that there is nothing that I can do about it myself, but is there something that can be displayed on the screen to the reviewer when they are reviewing tag wiki edits.

I have never seen the tag wiki edit review screen before so I wouldn't know if there is any kind of help text there already.

Comment: why not  http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @NullPonyPointer tag wiki pages and tag wiki excerpt features are common to all stack exchange sites, so I think that this kind of think can happen on any stack exchange site, I had assumed that meta.stackoverflow was the correct place to post messages that apply to all stack exchange sites

Comment: I'd have rejected the wiki too, as it is a copy of Wiki page's description. **The story follows Daniel Rigg being put in a series of tests in order to try and let go of his obsession of saving everyone, whilst at the same time attempting to save his partner.**

Comment: @BackinaFlash it is not a copy, it is different to any other source and they are my own words. It's your choice to see it that way and as a reviewer you can reject things if you think you should. My point is that the reviewer has rejected the edit on the basis of the tag wiki excerpt being similar to the tag wiki page both of which I have authored. The reason "Two edits two the same tag." is an indication that the reviewer feels that I have edited the same tag twice. I am suggesting that there should be some way to make it clear that there is a difference between a tag wiki and a tag excerpt.

Comment: The reason which @Ankit has give is wrong, I agree. But it solely depends on the reviewers to either reject or accept the edits. For eg. I'd point out [tag:pygst] from SO. The user suggested same content [for excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1775584) and [the wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1775583) which were both accepted with just one rejection from me in the wiki. Your question has been asked a lot of times ([my favorite of them being this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141100/212576)).