# Is it wrong for me to edit posts/titles for proper grammar, punctuation and capitalization?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should users edit other users' posts to correct grammar and spelling problems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-users-edit-other-users-posts-to-correct-grammar-and-spelling-problems)

I'm a bit of a stickler for properly formatted titles and questions. Nothing irks me more than logging into SuperUser only to see a large portion of the question titles using bad punctuation, no capitalization and even 'txt speak'.

I'd like to edit each and every one of these that I see. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: You misspelled punctuation in your initial version of this title

Comment: AH! Nice catch :)

Comment: It is encoraged to fix teh gramer and puncture of posts.

Comment: Ooh, the original has a 2-digit post id.  That's an old one. :)

Comment: That's surely 'txt-spk'? ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's encouraged.  Clearly written questions are easier to answer.

I usually don't worry about punctuation and capitalization unless I find something else to edit, but text speak is an active barrier to getting an answer.

Comment: +1 Text speak is caustic to my eyes.....

Answer (score 6):

If you mean "Does it show that I'm a bit OCD", then yes, it does :P  But if you are asking whether it's appropriate to edit other people's posts to improve their grammar, then I assume that it's ok to do that. After all, that's what the option is there for and abuse is prevented by restricting it to high rep users.