# Beta sites' front pages don't have chat banners

Tags: feature-request, chat, beta-sites, homepage

I have noticed that beta sites seem never to show chat room activity on their front page banner, although they do on their metas. Is there a reason for this?

Could the front page chat banner be added to beta sites?

This is significant, especially given how many beta sites are around and how old some of them are.

Comment: This isn't Twitter - please use correct grammar and spelling when posting on Stack Exchange and avoid "txtspeak" (such as "esp").

Comment: _DK and where is that official se policy? this isnt english class or middle school either!_

Comment: @vzn - Related to your grammar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47391/194162 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178940/194162

Comment: there is no "grammar question". the two cited posts are unrelated. have no general objections to others editing posts & after many dozens of questions have never flunked an se grammar filter. any "objection" is others obsessing about irrelevant/ harmless/ inconsequential minutia & "circling the wagons" etc.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't shown because most beta sites don't have dedicated chats. Also, it isn't shown on lots of sites sometimes simply because of cacheing and even inactivity can disable them. That is a good idea though, I'd love to see the banner on beta sites with active chats. Always so hard to actually find their chats.

Comment: many graduated sites dont have active chats either. the main page chat banner is already designed to only appear if there is recent activity in that sites chat rooms. changing that logic to occasionally display the banner/ chat room section even if it wasnt recently active would be nice too but isnt the main "feature requested".

Comment: @vzn edited. thanks for the tip.